# Get distinct Combination of item pairs from Array[String] Column

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe

```scala
val input = Seq(("ZZ","a","a","b","b"),
("ZZ","a","b","c","d"),
("YY","b","e",null,"f"),
("YY","b","b",null,"f"),
("VV","a",null,"",""))
.toDF("main","value1","value2","value3","value4")
input.show()

+----+------+------+------+------+
|main|value1|value2|value3|value4|
+----+------+------+------+------+
|  ZZ|     a|     a|     b|     b|
|  ZZ|     a|     b|     c|     d|
|  YY|     b|     e|  null|     f|
|  YY|     b|     b|  null|     f|
|  VV|     a|  null|      |      |
+----+------+------+------+------+
```

I did the following to flatten out the data

```
val newdf = input.select('main,array('value1,'value2,'value3,'value4).alias("values"))
.groupBy('main).agg(collect_set('values).alias("values"))
.select('main, flatten($"values").alias("values"))
newdf.show()

+----+--------------------+
|main|              values|
+----+--------------------+
|  ZZ|[a, a, b, b, a, b...|
|  YY|[b, e,, f, b, b,, f]|
|  VV|            [a,, , ]|
+----+--------------------+
```

Now I need to pick every unique combination of items as a pair from the array and have them as separate rows of data. So for the dataframe given above, the result will be

```
+----+------+------+
|main|value1|value2|
+----+------+------+
|  ZZ|     a|     b|
|  ZZ|     a|     c|
|  ZZ|     a|     d|
|  ZZ|     b|     c|
|  ZZ|     d|     c|
|  YY|     b|     f|
|  YY|     b|     e|
|  YY|     e|     f|
|  VV|     a|      |
+----+------+------+
```

How do I reduce to column to unique items that I can split out as separate rows ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `explode` two times and filter.

```
val newdf = input.select('main,array('value1,'value2,'value3,'value4).alias("values"))
.groupBy('main).agg(flatten(collect_set('values)).alias("values"))
.withColumn("value1", explode(array_distinct('values)))
.withColumn("value2", explode(array_distinct('values)))
.filter("value1 < value2")
.select('main, 'value1, 'value2)
newdf.show()

+----+------+------+
|main|value1|value2|
+----+------+------+
|  ZZ|     a|     b|
|  ZZ|     a|     c|
|  ZZ|     a|     d|
|  ZZ|     b|     c|
|  ZZ|     b|     d|
|  ZZ|     c|     d|
|  YY|     b|     e|
|  YY|     b|     f|
|  YY|     e|     f|
|  VV|      |     a|
+----+------+------+
```

Comment: This logic works perfectly but when for a single row the values are `("XX", "a", null, null)` the filter filters out the entire row and we loose out the "a" value. 

I worked around this by substituting the null with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

`I need to pick every unique combination of items as a pair`, like if ZZ has values [a,b,c,d] then essentially you will create 6 pairs (4 choose 2)? In such case, you may want to create a UDAF (user defined aggregate function).

```scala
input
.select('main,array('value1,'value2,'value3,'value4).alias("values"))
.groupBy('main).agg(<here comes your UDAF>)
```

This UDAF should be such that it collects values as a set (or list then `.distinct`) and produces all combination pairs (can be done with 2 for loops).

After this point, your dataframe should look like

```scala
+----+------------------------------------+
|main|              values                |
+----+------------------------------------+
|  ZZ|[(a,b),(a,c),(a,d),(b,c),(b,d),(c,d)|
+----+------------------------------------+
```

Then you can `.explode()` to get a dataframe like

```scala
+----+-------+
|main|values |
+----+-------+
|  ZZ|(a,b)  |
+----+-------+
|  ZZ|(a,c)  |
+----+-------+
|  ZZ|(a,d)  |
+----+-------+
|  ZZ|(b,c)  |
+----+-------+
|  ZZ|(b,d)  |
+----+-------+
|  ZZ|(c,d)  |
+----+-------+
```

Then you can make column `value1` as first value of this tuple and column `value2` as second value.